# Flutter Error: No named parameter with the name 'isVisible' error on url_launcher_web and pointer_interceptor

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

after running `flutter pub upgrade` I get these errors when I run flutter build web

```
../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pointer_interceptor-0.9.2/lib/src/web.dart:31:6: Error: No named parameter with the name 'isVisible'.
  }, isVisible: false);
     ^^^^^^^^^

../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_web-2.0.7/lib/url_launcher_web.dart:50:61: Error: No named parameter with the name 'isVisible'.
        .registerViewFactory(linkViewType, linkViewFactory, isVisible: false);
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with `url_launcher_web` which did not solve by running `flutter pub get`. In my case upgrading the flutter version fixed the problem.

Before:

```
Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 18116933e7 (4 months ago) • 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
Engine • revision d3ea636dc5
Tools • Dart 2.14.4
```

After:

```
Flutter 2.10.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5f105a6ca7 (3 days ago) • 2022-02-01 14:15:42 -0800
Engine • revision 776efd2034
Tools • Dart 2.16.0 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

Comment: working fine for me in 2.5.3 but i update flutter to 2.10.3 than again due to some reason i want to switch back to 2.5.3 now i'm getting this error and cannot able to solve. :(

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Url_launcher 6.0.18 automatically updated the internal library url_launcher_web from 2.0.6 to 2.0.7.
Now 2.0.7 uses flutter 2.10 and 2.0.6 uses flutter 2.5. They did that without "requiring" flutter 2.10 (which they fixed with url_launcher 2.0.8). But if you're still at flutter <2.10 you'll have an issue.

There is 2 options you have here:

1. cheap option. (I am using this now right now as a "hotfix"): Add this to your pubspec.yaml (below dependencies or dev_dependencies)

> ```
> dependency_overrides:
>   url_launcher_web: 2.0.6
> ```

This just makes url_launcher load the "right" version.

2. The right option would be to upgrade your sdk to flutter 2.10 (with flutter upgrade). Maybe you just don't want to do that right now but you eventually should.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line into **pubspec.yaml** as shown in the image

```
dependency_overrides:
  url_launcher_web: 2.0.6
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I searched `isVisible: false` property in `url_launcher_web` and `pointer_interceptor` packages files in the flutter dependencies directory and deleted them. After running `flutter pub get` in the terminal the errors were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

dependency_overrides:
url_launcher_web: 2.0.6   in your  pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I am also extending the answer that I am also facing this same issue and below solution is working for me.
I have opened `url_launcher_web.dart` file from Dart Packages and go to `url_launcher_web-2.0.7`. After `url_launcher_web.dart` files I have removed `isVisible: false` from `registerWith()` method. like below

> Before :

```
static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
    UrlLauncherPlatform.instance = UrlLauncherPlugin();
    ui.platformViewRegistry
        .registerViewFactory(linkViewType, linkViewFactory, isVisible: false);
  }
```

> After:

```
static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
    UrlLauncherPlatform.instance = UrlLauncherPlugin();
    ui.platformViewRegistry
        .registerViewFactory(linkViewType, linkViewFactory);
  }
```

See as below whom using Android Studio:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with url_launcher_web which did not solve by running flutter pub get. In my case adding  this line on index.html fixed the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to load right version. run this:
flutter clean;
flutter pub get;

then rebuild

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).